# How to iterate over list of tables and find proportions in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a list of tables in R in which each table is a column from a larger dataset. These are tables instead of dataframes as I want to use prop.table to find the percentage of occurance for the data.

I'm new to R so I have been manually finding the percentage one-by-one for each table. I am trying to make this a for loop instead but it doesn't seem to work. The loop is looping the correct number of times but it is giving me the results for the last table "Actually_Malicious" each time it opens a new View() table.

```
categorical_variables_list = list(Download_Source, 
                                  TLD, 
                                  Download_Speed, 
                                  Executable_Code_Maybe_Present_in_Headers,
                                  No_Executable_Code_Found_In_Headers,
                                  Evidence_of_Code_Obfuscation,
                                  Actually_Malicious)


for(col in 1:length(categorical_variables_list)){
  
  tab <- table(categorical_variables_list[[col]]); 
  View(tab);
  prop <- prop.table(tab); 
  View(prop);
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I agree, I should have created a reproducible example but I figured that this type of question would not require it as I thought it was more about how I was attempting to access the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this, If you put a sample of your data the answer could be much cleaner and clearer, You can try below, however you can also choose `lapply`, I have added mine list of columns(used mtcars dataset here):

```
categorical_variables_list<- list(mtcars[['cyl']], mtcars[['am']], mtcars[['vs']])

tab <- vector('list', length(categorical_variables_list)) 
prop <- vector('list', length(categorical_variables_list))

for(col in 1:length(categorical_variables_list)){
  
  tab[[col]] <- table(categorical_variables_list[[col]]);

  prop[[col]] <- prop.table(tab[[col]]) 

}
```

Your final results will be inside tab and prop. Using lapply you can do like below:

```
tab <- lapply(categorical_variables_list,table)
prop <- lapply(tab, prop.table)
```

**Explanation**:

Initialising the tab/prop here in the code, you can also do list(), but it doesn't tell R how long the length of list is , using vector('list', length(...)) is both used for convenience as well efficient execution of for loops, for loops if initialized properly runs with speed. the argument of vector are as follows, the first argument is the kind of data you want to create, suppose if you want to create a numeric atomic vector instead of list then you can write vector('numeric', length(...)) etc for other types, here I wanted list hence written as vector('list', length(...)), second argument is nothing but length of for loop it should run for (how many times), since I know it will run for length of your list. it's mentioned that  way. I hope this clears all the doubt. The lapply is easy, lapply catches the first argument as list, the later argument is the function which will iterate on each of the elements present in the list(It's very similar to what your loop is doing but its more convenient and also you don't have to initialize the objects )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you mind briefly explaining the difference between using vector() and lapply()?

Comment: @VehicularIT added it